# Registered CancellationToken callback invocation order

Tags: c#, async-await

If I register some callbacks to a `CancellationToken` before it is cancelled, it seems they will be invoked in **reverse order** when the token is cancelled. Is this invocation order guaranteed?

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = cts.Token;
token.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("1"));
token.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("2"));
token.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("3"));
cts.Cancel();
```

This will output

```
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, from [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationTokenSource.cs,3678511246a677b5) of class CancellationToken it appears to be so. The method `ExecuteCallbackHandlers(bool throwOnFirstException)` is responsible for getting callbacks and executing them. It contains this fragment of code:

```
try
{
   for (int index = 0; index < callbackLists.Length; index++)
   {
      SparselyPopulatedArray<CancellationCallbackInfo> list = Volatile.Read<SparselyPopulatedArray<CancellationCallbackInfo>>(ref callbackLists[index]);
      if (list != null)
      {
         SparselyPopulatedArrayFragment<CancellationCallbackInfo> currArrayFragment = list.Tail;

         while (currArrayFragment != null)
         {
             for (int i = currArrayFragment.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
             {
                ... some other code
             }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

In the inner `for` loop it traverses the fragment of array of callbacks backwards from last to first element.

However as noted by @Nick this is not guaranteed in the documentation. A simple solution would be to add callbacks into *one* delegate - this way we have more control over the execution order:

```
token.Register(() => 
{ 
   Console.WriteLine("1"));
   Console.WriteLine("2"));
   Console.WriteLine("3"));
});
```

Comment: Please note that this is an implementation detail and the calling order is not guaranteed in the documentation, so it can change in future releases.