# CancellationToken.Register(MyMethod). In what cases the method may not be called Methods execution order

Tags: c#, .net

In book Microsoft Visual C # Step by Step Ninth Edition John Sharp said:

> You can also register a callback method (in the form of an Action
> delegate) with the cancellation token by using the Register method.
> When an application invokes the Cancel method of the corresponding
> CancellationTokenSource object, this callback runs. However, you
> cannot guarantee when this method executes; it might be before or
> after the tasks have performed their own cancellation processing, or
> even during that process.
>
> cancellationToken.Register(doAdditionalWork);
>
> private void doAdditionalWork() { // Perform additional cancellation
> processing }

It's all.

**First question.**
I do not understand how this can be. Can someone give an example when a method is registered, the token is canceled, but for some reason the method that is registered has not been executed?

**Second question.**
The order of method calls. It is reverse. Why? Inside a stack of delegates??

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            void MyMethod(int a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a);
            }

            CancellationTokenSource MyCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken MyCancellationToken = MyCancellationTokenSource.Token;

            MyCancellationToken.Register(() => MyMethod(1));
            MyCancellationToken.Register(() => MyMethod(2));
            MyCancellationToken.Register(() => MyMethod(3));

            MyCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

            //Console:
            //3
            //2
            //1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For your second question: [Registered CancellationToken callback invocation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158432/registered-cancellationtoken-callback-invocation-order)

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel, Thanks! The second issue has been resolved.

Comment: @NikVladi "However, you cannot guarantee **when** this method executes; it might be before or after the tasks have performed their own cancellation processing, or even during that process.". It is *when*, not if! It *will* execute.

Comment: @PeterBons, Oh my God. Damn translator! I just trusted the translator and didn't look at the word When.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that execution order in multi threaded systems is not well defined. A thread may be suspended at any time for theoretically any length of time. Ordering is only guaranteed within a thread. For example the following could happen

1. Cancel is called on thread A
2. `MyMethod` is queued to run (thread A)
3. Cancel token is marked as canceled (thread A)
4. The task checks the token, observes that it is cancelled, and aborts (thread B)
5. Scheduler gets around to calling `MyMethod` on thread C

It is unclear to me if there are any case where `MyMethod` would *never* run. The documentation for [CancellationToken.Register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register?view=net-6.0) states:

> Registers a delegate that will be called when this CancellationToken is canceled.

and

> If this token is already in the canceled state, the delegate will be run immediately and synchronously.

So I would assume that the registered method will always be called if the token is, or will be, canceled. But you cannot assume anything about *when* this it is done.