# Why is it always the last task in Task.WhenAny that gets completed first?

Tags: c#, task

The completed task is always `signal3Task`. Even if I shuffle `signal1Task`, `signal2Task` and `signal2Task` order in `Task.WhenAny` it has no effect.
But, if I change the order of creation of `signal1Task`, `signal2Task` and `signal3Task` tasks, then it has effect. Meaning if I swap between lines (1.) and (3.) then the completed task will be always `signal1Task` regardless of the order in `Task.WhenAny`. If I swap between lines (2.) and (3.) then the completed task will be always `signal2Task` regardless of the order in `Task.WhenAny`.

Is it just a coincidence?

```
    static async Task Main()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cancelTokenSource = new();
        
        AsyncManualResetEvent signal1 = new();
        AsyncAutoResetEvent signal2 = new();
        AsyncAutoResetEvent signal3 = new();
1.      var signal1Task = signal1.WaitAsync(cancelTokenSource.Token);
2.      var signal2Task = signal2.WaitAsync(cancelTokenSource.Token);
3.      var signal3Task = signal3.WaitAsync(cancelTokenSource.Token);
        
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
        });
        
        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(signal1Task, signal2Task, signal3Task);       
        if (completedTask == signal1Task)
            Console.WriteLine("signal1Task");
        if (completedTask == signal2Task)
            Console.WriteLine("signal2Task");
        if (completedTask == signal3Task)
            Console.WriteLine("signal3Task");
    }
```

Comment: It is likely that this is the order in which `cancelTokenSource.Cancel();` cancels tasks. Because it is the order in which those were registered. But in reality this is an implementation detail, and you should not make any assumptions about the order.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Registered CancellationToken callback invocation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158432/registered-cancellationtoken-callback-invocation-order)

Comment: Indeed..seems to be the Cancel order  tied to the last registered task. Digging further i found that (idk if this code is for real purposes) if i play with CancelationTokenSource cancel time and/or task delay the task status is always returning Canceled.

Comment: Why would you care which order? Interesting no doubt, but shouldn't make a difference to your code.